# Controlling single output component using two or more microcontrollers

Tags: diodes, raspberry-pi

iam making a raspberry pi project which controls a 8channel relay board. Now the task is to control single 8channel relay board with two raspberry pi's. The output of RPi-1 should not interfere the RPi-2. So can i use the diodes to avoid interferance between the both RPi's. The below block diagram gives clarity on my question  [image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please capitalise properly (including 'Raspberry' and 'Pi') and get your diagrams oriented properly.

Comment: Look at open drain schemes with a pull up and two open drain pins

Answer (score 1):

One of your diodes is in the wrong place.

[image]

This might work but you have failed to link to the relay module datasheet in your question so I don't know whether it's on when the input is high or low.